# MATLAB - Event Location fail to work?

Tags: matlab, events, ode

The event location function fail in finding an easy event when solving a 4 variables system of ode. Here's the code:

```
options1 = odeset('RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-9,'Events',@evento1); 
[T_ode1,X_ode1,te]=ode15s(@Seno,[0 2],[0 0 0 0 0],options1);

function [y] = Seno(t,x)

%Parameters 
V=20;
R=1e6;
epsilon=8.87e-12;
d=4.5e-5;
k_sp=10;
gamma1=0.04;
gamma2=0.1;
m=66e-3;
A=0.1;
omega=80;
h=3.8e-6;
l=2e-3;
N=142;

%Variable redefinition
%x=[x,xpunto,q,y,ypunto] 
X=x(1);
Xp=x(2);
Q=x(3);
Y=x(4);
Yp=x(5);

%sistema eq differenziali
y(1)=Xp; %y1(1)=position1
y(2)=-(2*k_sp*X/m)-(gamma1*Xp/m)+((epsilon*2*d*h*N*l)*X*V^2/((d^2-X^2)^2))+A*sin(omega*t); %y1(2)=velocity1
y(3)=1/R*(V-Q*(d^2-X^2)/(epsilon*2*d*h*N*l)); %y1(3)=charge
y(4)=Yp; %position 2
y(5)=-gamma2*Yp; %velocity2
y=y';
end 

function [condition,ends,directions] = evento1(t,y)
a=2e-6;
c=2e-6;
b=1.5e-6;
condition= [(y(1)^2)-(a+c)^2, (y(4)^2)-(y(1)+b)^2, (y(4)^2)-(y(1)-b)^2];
ends = [1, 1, 1];  % Halt integration
directions = [1, -1, 1];   
end
```

Setting all the initial condition to 0, as you can see, the first event that the event function should find is when the tird condition when y(1) pass for 1.5e-6 (y(4) is 0). Unfortunally ode ignore that event and stop the solution when the 1st one is satisfied.

I can't see why this happen! I tryed the debugging mode and the systems properly pass across 1.5e-6 but doesn't consider it as an event (ie it doesn't start to evaluate the solution in more points near the event).

Thanks for your time and sorry for my english.

Comment: An obvious issue is that the output variable names of `evento1` don't match any of the variables in side the function. Typo? If not, please edit to provide a basic runnable example that replicates your issue.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited: when i posted the script here i changed the names of the variables from Italian to English. Btw in my script on matlab they are ok

Comment: You may be dealing with numerical precision or a parameter may not be specified accurately. I suggest that you plot the values of your `condition` using the values of `X_ode1` returned by the simulation. You'll see exactly what is going on: the first condition approaches very close to zero and then reverses direction (even if I adjust tolerances).

Comment: The fact is that the system seems to recognise the first condition (indeed it stops when y(1)=4e-6) but skips the third (ie y(1)=1.5e-6) even if I put it near the first . That is really really odd .

Comment: FYI, there's a typo in my comment above: "first" should be "third". If you plot your `condition` over time, I think you'll see that the third case never reaches zero and so never triggers an event. Provide runnable code (including initial conditions, etc.) that shows what you mean by "skipping" the third case.

Comment: Code updated (of course you need to create the two functions separately )

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, you can plot your event conditions after simulating the system:

```
options1 = odeset('RelTol',1e-5,'AbsTol',1e-9,'Events',@evento1); 
[T_ode1,X_ode1,te] = ode15s(@Seno,[0 2],[0 0 0 0 0],options1);

a = 2e-6;
c = 2e-6;
b = 1.5e-6;
y = X_ode1;
condition = [y(:,1).^2-(a+c)^2 y(:,4).^2-(y(:,1)+b).^2 y(:,4).^2-(y(:,1)-b).^2];
figure;
plot(T_ode1,condition);
hold on;
plot(T_ode1([1 end]),[0 0],'k--',te,0,'k*');
legend('Condition 1','Condition 2','Condition 3','Location','W');
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('State');
ylim([-1.8e-11 2e-12]);
```

This results in a plot that looks like this:

[image: event condition plot]

If you zoom in on the plot you'll see that the third condition (yellow) never crosses zero and thus never triggers an event. Eventually the first event (blue) crosses zero and does trigger an event. Adjusting the integration tolerances doesn't appear to change this behavior (at best the third condition *might* asymptotically touch, but not cross, zero). If you want the third condition to trigger an event, you'll either need to change your parameters, change the condition, change your initial conditions, or change your ODEs.

I'm not sure if or why you think the third condition should cross zero, but if the system is numerically sensitive, then you may need to compensate for this by specifying parameter more precisely or artificially biasing the point of zero crossing.

Comment: I think that the tird condition needs to trigger before the 1st one because y(1) actually crosses the event but "skip over it" . I mean as you can see in the plot y(1) start away from 1.5e-6 , the goes near it and the 2nd condition is almost 0, then pass over it. It can be easily seen looking explicity in a plot y(1) vs t . But thanks for the advises.